# storing user input from form and displaying summary

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I created a form, and I want to use jquery to store the labels and the user inputted input value into an array. At the bottom of the form, there is a next button instead of submit. When the user presses next, they should see a summary of all of the labels and their input. The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="form-item">
    <label>Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="form-item">
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

I believe the best way to go about this is to loop thorugh each `div.form-item` using `each()` like so:

```
$(".form-item").each(function(){
     var label = $(this).find('label').text(); 
     var input = $(this).find('input').val();
});
```

Im not sure how to go about collecting multiple chunks of form items using unique variables. I want this to be completely dynamic, so regardless of how many form fields there are, it will work. DO I store them in an array? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: it should be `$(".form-item").each...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` method, also note that your class selector is not correct, you have missed a `.`.

```
var arr = $('.form-item').map(function() {
               var lab = $('label', this).text();
               var val = $('input', this).val();
               return lab + val;
          }).get()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5Z6C/2/

Comment: is there an advantage of using map over a normal array/push?

Comment: @JCHASE11 `map` also uses `push` method,  this is only a jQuery way of creating an array.

Comment: Thanks, and how would var arr be displayed?

Comment: You are welcome. I have used  `console.log` in the fiddle, you can also use `alert`.

Comment: If I remove the value, and type in my own value, it doe not store the value in the array. See: http://jsfiddle.net/b5Z6C/5/

Comment: @JCHASE11 You should put the `map` inside the click handler, try this http://jsfiddle.net/b5Z6C/6/

Comment: this works great, thanks. How would I append var arr to a selector like so:  $("body").append(arr); (it is not working for me)

Comment: I get this error with the above code:  Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Comment: @JCHASE11 You should convert the array to a string, `$("body").append(arr.join(''))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16562/discussion-between-jchase11-and-undefined)

Comment: Thanks! This also needs to work for select menu and textarea, would the best method be doing a conditional statement saying if the children of form item = textarea, do this.... or what would be a good way of going about this?

Comment: @JCHASE11 You are welcome. Sorry, you should post an another question for this.

Comment: will do, I will post the link here when it is posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376787/using-jquery-map-with-multiple-types-of-form-elements

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in an array like:

```
var els = new Array();
$(".form-item").each(function(){
  els.push({
    label: $(this).find('label').text(), 
    value: $(this).find('input').val()});
});
```

Later in the code you can do:

```
for(var i in els){
  $('.where-you-want-it')
    .append('<p>'+els[i].label+'</p><span>'+els[i].value+'</span>');
}
```

Comment: How would I display the array in a format like so: <p>label</p><span>value</span>?